# Spyder ipython console error: can't decode path

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

My problem is that when I start Spyder, the following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1544, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
config=None, autorestart=True)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 73, in __init__
super(Configurable, self).__init__(**kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 997, in __init__
setattr(self, key, value)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 585, in __set__
self.set(obj, value)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 559, in set
new_value = self._validate(obj, value)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 591, in _validate
value = self.validate(obj, value)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 2053, in validate
raise TraitError(msg.format(value, self.name, class_of(obj)))
TraitError: Could not decode 'C:\\Users\\Jos\xe9 Miguel\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel�f89b82d15.json' for unicode trait 'connection_file' of a QtKernelManager instance.
```

I have tried to install Anaconda2 in a path that includes only Unicode characters (especifically `C:\Anaconda2\`), but it doesn't work neither.
I hope someone can help me. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You have two options to fix this:

1. Rename your user home directory (i.e. `C:\\Users\\Jos\xe9 Miguel`) to something that doesn't have unicode characters nor spaces (e.g. `C:\\Users\\Jose`)
2. Create a new Windows user without unicode characters nor spaces and install Anaconda there.

Comment: I have also installed Anaconda3 in my computer. Why there isn't any error in Spyder3 whereas in Spyder2 appears the above one?

Comment: Because Python 3 has much better support for Unicode than Python 2. That was one of major points on creating Python 3 in the first place. Besides, as you can see from the error above, this problem is not exactly in Spyder but in a different library.

Comment: @Josemi If you have installed Anaconda3, do you need Anaconda2?

Comment: Well, in fact, I no longer need Anaconda2, because our lecturer told us we were going to use Python 2.7, but I asked him if I could use Python 3.6 and it was ok, so I don't have this problem fortunately, but thanks for the answer.